# How to get the value from a timedelta?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When SQLalchemy returns:

```
{u'age': datetime.timedelta(12045),}
```

how do I get the 12045?  I've tried `str()`, `strftime()`, and a bunch of others, but nothing works.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), use `.total_seconds()` to get the length of a timedelta.  Note that the timedelta you've provided is showing a days value, but a timedelta includes seconds and microseconds as well.  If you just want the days, use `.days`.

```
age = datetime.timedelta(12045)
print(age.total_seconds())  # 1040688000.0
print(age.days)  # 12045, but not the full value represented by the delta
```